# How to bind boolean value to label

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF.  My code is as follows:

In my **MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="63,30,0,0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="{Binding myVal}" Height="39" Width="71"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btnSelect" Content="Select" Click="btnSelect_Click_1" Margin="396,0,10,0"/>
</Grid>
```

and **MainWindow.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _myboolVal;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void btnSelect_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (myVal== false)
        {
            myVal = true;
        }
        else
        {
            myVal= true;
        }
    }

    public bool myVal
    {
        get { return _myboolVal; }
        set { _myboolVal= value; OnPropertyChanged("myVal"); }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

But the value of the label is always `false`.

Comment: That should work.  Trace it out in debug.

Comment: if statement useless, u can simply assign true to `myVal`

Comment: You have `myVal = true;` in both `if` and `else` cases.  Also, if you would like to stay true to the MVVM pattern, you should have your event in the `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic in `btnSelect_Click_1` is incorrect. Update it to:

```
private void btnSelect_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myVal = !myVal;
}
```

Comment: @kyle If this is the answer then inconsistent with the problem statement "But the value of the label is always false".

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this [sample](https://github.com/dzmtrmartavoi/WpfSample1.git) (MVVM, Command binding, MVVMLight)

Comment: I want to change the value of label at every click

Comment: @kyle: you can bind Text prop. of the label to an appropriate property of a viewmodel and change it in Command.Execute

Answer (score 0):

Please set the Mode to TwoWay ,then it will works.

Content="{Binding myVal,Mode=TwoWay}"